# C++ Open-MPI: custom struct type Not able to send over Ssend

Tags: c++, mpi, distributed-computing

So I am working on a project using MPI and I am trying to create my own structure. The problem I am having is that it seems to not be working correctly as I never receive anything inside the worker and so I time out. I tried with a standard MPI_INT and it worked great. However, when I tried implementing my own type, it didn't like it... Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <mpi.h>
#include "main.hpp"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    //initialize MPI
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    message_to_worker message;
    //declare my new type
    MPI_Datatype MessageType;

    //declare the types the the structure will have
    MPI_Datatype type[1] = { MPI_INT };
    //the number of results for each type(int[50] will be 50 etc..)
    int blocklen[1] = {1};

    //this will store the displacement for each var in the structure
    MPI_Aint disp[1] = {0};
    MPI_Aint var1, var2;

    //number of vars
    int count = 1;

    //define the type
    MPI_Type_struct(count, blocklen, disp, type, &MessageType);
    MPI_Type_commit(&MessageType); 

    std::cout << "The displacement is " << disp[0] << std::endl;

    int rank;
    int world_size;

    //give me my current rank(node 1 reiceves 1 , node 2 etc... )
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_size);

    int counter = 1;
    message.N = 5;

    //IF MASTER
    if (rank == 0) {
        int result;

        //send messages to the workers
        while(counter<world_size){
            //send 1 message of type MessageType using my own structure(first parameter)
            result = MPI_Ssend(&message, 1, MessageType, counter, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            //make sure the mssage was sent correctly
            if (result == MPI_SUCCESS){
                std::cout << "I am master and the world size is : " << world_size << std::endl;
                std::cout << " I send a message to mky worker thread " << std::endl;
            }else{
                std::cout << "There was a problem with the sending for worker " << counter << std::endl;
            }
            counter++;
        }
    }
    //IF WORKER
    else if (rank > 0) {
        //the worker will wait until it receives a message
        int result = MPI_Recv(&message, 1, MessageType, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD,
                  MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        //make sure the message was RECEIVED correctly
        if (result == MPI_SUCCESS){
            std::cout << "Worker - Rank: " << rank <<" OK! and the value received through the message is " << message.N << std::endl;
        }
    }

    //shutdown MPI
    MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: please make your solution into an answer, wait for the timer to time out and accept it.

Comment: An unsolicited advice: checking the return value of MPI communication calls is pointless unless you've explicitly changed the error handler for the communicator (which you haven't done). The default handler terminates the program on error and that's why you'll never see any return code other than `MPI_SUCCESS`.

Comment: @HristoIliev, thank you. I definitely did not know that and I appreciate the advice!

Answer (score 0):

My tag param(3 param from last) was different for the sender and receiver.. The master was using tag 123, and the worker was looking for tag 0. They both need to be synched since they need to establish a communication channel. Here is the fix(notice how the 5th paramenter, the tag, changed).

**Before:**

```
MPI_Ssend(&message, 1, MessageType, counter, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Recv(&message, 1, MessageType, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```

**After**

```
MPI_Ssend(&message, 1, MessageType, counter, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

MPI_Recv(&message, 1, MessageType, 0, 123, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
```